# Complex conjugate of the following expression

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

suppose that we have f is a scalar. And we have the expression $H=Re(f)+Im(f)$. If I want to take the complex conjugate of $H$, does this become $\bar{H}=Re(f)-Im(f)$ or this doesn't make sense?

Comment: $H$ is the sum of two real numbers, which is also a real number. Therefore it's conjugate is...

Comment: how do you know that H is a real number?

Comment: Because $H$ is defined as the sum of two real numbers.

Comment: is Im(f) a real number?

Comment: if f is complex, is Im(f) real number? Now when it is mentioned in the question that f is a scalar (f could be complex or real).

Comment: Yes, always....

Answer (score 1):

Try thinking in terms of $\operatorname{Re}{f} = \frac{1}{2}(f+\bar{f})$ and $\operatorname{Im}{f} = \frac{1}{2i}(f-\bar{f})$. Given that and $\bar{i}=-i$, $\overline{\bar{f}} = f$, you should be able to find the correct expression.